# Android App installation error with a previous backup

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am loading an earlier project (that I saved earlier) from android studio. When I press 'Run', I see below error

[image]

When I press OK, I see below error in the 'Run' tab. How do I solve this? I have tried running adb independently from 'platform-tools' but get the similar error.

[image]

Comment: I had this popup apearing when there was some kind of issue in the build.gradle file(s), and unninstalling the app didn't solve it. Are you trying to install on the emulator (x86) and using only armeabi libs for example?

Comment: no, installing on a pixel phone

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: Hey are you try to uninstall manually from settings and App section then select app which you want to uninstall  and uninstall it and run again it may be fix your problem